# Execute script for all but certain files in directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need a bash script to iterate on all files in directory besides one with specific names. Maybe it can be done with help of awk/sed during script execution?

Here is my script, that simply merge all file in directory to one:

```
 #!/bin/bash
(find $DIR_NAME -name app.gz\* | sort -rV | xargs -L1 gunzip -c 2> /dev/null || :)
```

How can I add some $DIR_NAME to list, and don`t iterate over them?

Comment: Can you give an example of paths you want to include and paths you want to exclude?

Comment: It`s basically directory of directories in final folder are several txt files. 
I execute bash script like this: 
```
for updir in /home/logger/??; do for dir in $updir/*; ./cat_files.sh > DB.log
```
Example:
Include name: /home/logger/Andy 
Exclude name: /home/logger/Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the names of the files to be excluded into a file, say "blacklist.txt", one filename per line. Then use

```
... | grep -F -f blacklist.txt | sort ...
```

to exclude them from the input to xargs.

Comment: @user194428 Thanks! But can I do so with directory names?

Comment: Your `find` command outputs the path, which includes directorynames. You would only run into trouble, if a directory name happens to be the same as a file name. You can work around this if you put into `blacklist.txt` enough of the path to uniquely identify those entries which need to be blacklisted.